# Reinstall orchard cms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

Is there any possibility to reinstall (create conpact edition database file) from orchard cms ?

I've deleted the database file , and now when I am launching the orchard I am getting to directory browsing page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete the whole App_Data folder if you want to start over.